# Using loop in select query column name

Tags: oracle11g

```
create or replace PROCEDURE NG_SP_TEST_ZAPIN 
as
i number;
q nvarchar2(100);
BEGIN
    i:=1;
   select ftrquestion1 into q from NG_ZAPIN_FTRCHECKLIST where wi_name=1;
   select ftrquestion2 into q from NG_ZAPIN_FTRCHECKLIST where wi_name=1;
   select ftrquestion3 into q from NG_ZAPIN_FTRCHECKLIST where wi_name=1;
   select ftrquestion4 into q from NG_ZAPIN_FTRCHECKLIST where wi_name=1;
   select ftrquestion5 into q from NG_ZAPIN_FTRCHECKLIST where wi_name=1;
   select ftrquestion6 into q from NG_ZAPIN_FTRCHECKLIST where wi_name=1;
   select ftrquestion7 into q from NG_ZAPIN_FTRCHECKLIST where wi_name=1;
   select ftrquestion8 into q from NG_ZAPIN_FTRCHECKLIST where wi_name=1;    
END;
```

I have to select a particular column from table which has same prefix, the last value alone changes as 0..10, instead of writing 10 select query can I put in a loop and iterate with appending i(for loop value) as last character of column..

Answer (score 0):

You should get all fields in one query and split the data in your code. And as I read your code, with each line you overwrite the previous selection?

```
select ftrquestion1,
ftrquestion2,
ftrquestion3,
ftrquestion[...]
into q from NG_ZAPIN_FTRCHECKLIST where wi_name=1;
```

Where q is an string array, but I am not aware of the language you use and how it saves a select set into an array.
Or do I get your request wrong?

Comment: The actual work is there are columns ftrquestion(0..10) and ftranswer(0..10) in the same row but I need as ftrquestion0 and ftranswer0 in one row and it repeats until ftrquestion10  and ftranswer10..Help me out on this..

Comment: I guess your datatable is not in a normalized form?It is quite a dirty approach you are using there. A dirty solution would be a string concatenation in a loop. So do a loop from 0 to 10 and add the iteration  as text to your field like "Select ftrquestion + loopVariable, ftranswer + loopvariable into q from [...]".

Comment: Are you sure concatenation in oracle is done by "+", bcos it is giving an error. Kindly check and post the exact query as I can use it as it is.Error(8,12): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "FTRQUESTION": invalid identifier